# What happens to files in my documents folder when I resign my iOS enterprise app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, certificate, enterprise, provisioning-profile

I can't find in the Apple iOS Documentation what will happen to files of documents folder when I have to resign the app at the expiry of provisiong profile / certificate. The only link that I found is: **https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/certificates/** where Apple explains what will happen if the certificate expires.
Can you link me a page of the Apple Documentation about this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about the contents of an app's sandbox on a user's iOS device? Why would the sandbox be affected in any way by resigning the app?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand if when I resign the app file on documents folder will be lost or not.

Comment: Resigning has no effect. Updating the app has no effect.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy, do you have a link that confirm that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer to my question:

http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/?lang=en-us#app43ad802c